# Video Carousel for SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts

Is there an out-of-the-box solution for a Web Part that displays a carousel based on a SharePoint list.

Basically it needs to show a carousel of video thumbnails and open a Url when clicking on a video.

I think it is doable for us with SPFx but before going that way I wanted to make sure there isn't something ready out there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video Carousel web part is available in SharePoint store. I find two apps in the store, they are free. Hope this helps you.

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104379870?tab=Overview

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA103980480?tab=Overview

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely try those ones out.